# Big-O analysis of recurrence relation

Tags: asymptotics, recurrence-relations, computational-complexity, recursive-algorithms, analysis-of-algorithms

I'm not sure if I should be posting this question here or under Stackoverflow, but given that it's algorithmic analysis, I figured Math was the right call. I have 2
functions that I'm trying to find the recurrence relation function to.

Function 1:

$T(2) = T(1)$

$T(4) = 2*T(2)$

$T(8) = 3*T(4)$

$T(16) = 4*T(8)$

$...$

$T(n) = log_2n*T(n/2)$

How is it derived that $T(n)$'s tightest bound is of time complexity $O((log_2n)!)$?

Function 2:

$T(2) = 2*T(1)$

$T(4) = 4*T(2)$

$T(8) = 8*T(4)$

$T(16) = 16*T(8)$

$...$

$T(n) = n*T(n/2)$

Would the tight bound for this be $O(n!)$ then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We take $n$ to be a power of $2$. Now, in the first question we have the recurrence relation:

$$ T(n) = \log_2 n \cdot T\left( \frac{n}{2} \right) $$

We get, after expanding out the first few iterations:

$$ T(n) = \log_2 n \cdot \log_2 \left( \frac{n}{2} \right) \cdot \log_2 \left( \frac{n}{2^2} \right) \cdot \log_2 \left( \frac{n}{2^3} \right) \cdot ... \cdot T(2) $$

And from this we conclude:

$$ T(n) = \prod_{k = 0}^{\log_2 n} \log_2 \left( \frac{n}{2^k} \right) $$

Which can be rewritten as:

$$ T(n) = \prod_{k = 1}^{\log_2 n} \log_2 2^k = \prod_{k = 1}^{\log_2 n} k $$

And so we conclude:

$$ T(n) = \log_2 n ! $$

In the second question we have the recurrence:

$$ T(n) = n \cdot T\left( \frac{n}{2} \right) $$

We get, after expanding out the first few iterations:

$$ T(n) = n \cdot \frac{n}{2} \cdot \frac{n}{2^2} \cdot \frac{n}{2^3} \cdot ... \cdot T(2) $$

From which we conclude:

$$ T(n) = \prod_{k = 0}^{\log_2 n} \frac{n}{2^k} = \prod_{k = 1}^{\log_2 n} 2^k $$

Taking the logarithm base 2 of each side we get:

$$ \log_2 T(n) = \sum_{k = 1}^{\log_2 n} k = \frac{1}{2} (\log_2^2 n + \log_2 n) $$

Which means:

$$ T(n) = \sqrt{n}^{1 + \log_2 n} $$

Comment: How do you conclude that $T(n) = \prod_{k = 0}^{\log_2 n} \frac{n}{2^k} = \prod_{k = 1}^{\log_2 n} 2^k $?

Comment: We have that $n$ is a power of 2. Now, take for instance $n = 16$ then: $$ \prod_{k = 0}^4 \frac{n}{2^k} = 16 \cdot 8 \cdot 4 \cdot 2 \cdot 1 $$ which is equivalent to $$ \prod_{k = 1}^4 2^k = 2 \cdot 4 \cdot 8 \cdot 16 $$

Comment: I wanted to ask if there was an easier way to determine $$ T(n) = \sqrt{n}^{1 + \log_2 n} $$ from $$ \log_2 T(n) = \sum_{k = 1}^{\log_2 n} k = \frac{1}{2} (\log_2^2 n + \log_2 n) $$ other than converting the RHS back to an exponent and performing natural logarithm manipulations

Comment: We have $$ \log_2 T(n) =  \frac{1}{2} (\log_2^2 n + \log_2 n) $$ and so $$ T(n) = 2^{\log_2 T(n)} = 2^{\frac{1}{2} (\log_2^2 n + \log_2 n)} $$ $$ = 2^{\log_2^2 n \cdot \frac{1}{2}} 2^{ \log_2 n \cdot \frac{1}{2}} $$ $$ = n^{\frac{1}{2}\log_2 n} n^{\frac{1}{2}} = \sqrt{n}^{1 + \log_2 n}$$ I do not know an easier way to derive the result. Note here we work with logarithm base $2$.